# Is there a possible solution to this Python program?

Tags: python-3.x

```
 flag1 = True
 flag2 = True
 def test(x):

    if x % 2 ==0 :
         flag1 = True

    if x >=10:
         flag2 = True

    return flag1 and flag2

print(test(9))
```

The questions says to check an even number which is greater than 10. But after executing the code the following error pops up : **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag2' referenced before assignment**.

I come from C++ background and I just started learning python. If possible please offer some solution.

Edit:Thank you everyone for the amazing answers. I was able to rectify my mistake.

Comment: I think it's because the local variable 'flag2' was referenced before it has been assigned.

Comment: @wim I edited the code,still it shows the same fault.

Comment: That is because for Odd numbers flag1 never gets initialized inside the function. Same for numbers less than 10 in case of flag2. Check my answer below

Comment: pro-tip:  code like `if <comparison>: var = True` is usually better written directly as the assignment `var = <comparison>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just because `flag1` and `flag2` are initialized/assigned only when your program enters the `if` blocks. What if the `if`s are never gone through. `return` wouldn't find `flag1` and/or `flag2` then.
Therefore-

```
def test(x):

    flag1, flag2 = False, False #This statement is possible in python (because you are from C++)
    if x % 2 ==0 :
         flag1 = True

    if x >=10:
         flag2 = True

    return flag1 and flag2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either use the global statement like this

```
flag1 = False
flag2 = False

def test(x):
    global flag1
    global flag2

    if x % 2 ==0 :
        flag1 = True

    if x >= 10:
        flag2 = True

    return flag2 and flag2

print(test(9))
```

or define the flag variables inside the function, which is recommended as after calling the test function once, if it has changed the value of flag variable to True, the test function will show abnormality over successive calls, hence you need instance variable flags which would be defined inside the function.

```
def test(x):
    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False

    if x % 2 ==0 :
        flag1 = True

    if x >= 10:
        flag2 = True

    return flag1 and flag2

print(test(9))
```

BONUS: link for understanding UnboundLocalError and scoping
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python

Answer (score 1):

The namespace/scoping rules in Python are quite different than in C++. With the lines

```
flag1 = True
flag2 = True
```

you are obviously trying to initialize the two variables (as in C++), but for that 
to work here you must move them inside the function. Also, these should be initialized to `False` (otherwise they are only ever set to `True`...):

```
def test(x):
    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False
    if x % 2 ==0 :
        flag1 = True
    if x >=10:
        flag2 = True
    return flag1 and flag2
```

Now, **why** doesn't it work to initialize the variables outside of the function? In Python, a function has global access to *all* variables without the use of the `global` keyword, but crucially, only global *read* access. That is, the value of `flag1` and `flag2` defined at the module level (outside of the function) can be read from inside the `test` function. However, when `test` is compiled (which happens automatically when you run the program and the parser hits the "`def` line"), the compiler sees that values are written to `flag1` and `flag2` inside `test`, and so it concludes that these are *local* variables, meaning that the global `flag1` and `flag2` will be utterly disregarded inside the function. This in turn means that the name `flag1` and `flag2` are only defined whenever the `if`s are `True` (and so for even numbers >= 10 the function will run, but it will crash otherwise).

The solution I provided was to make `flag1` and `flag2` local variables. You can also make them (proper, writable) global variables by keeping them outside the function and specifying to the `test` function that it is allowed to both read *and write* to the global `flag1` and `flag2` using the `global` keyword, as shown in other answers. As I'm sure you know, this is usually not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def test(x):
    flag1 = False
    flag2 = False

    if x % 2 ==0 :
         flag1 = True

    if x >=10:
         flag2 = True

    return flag1 and flag2

print(test(9))
```

Answer (score -1):

Since flag1 and flag2 were not declared inside the function, if the second condition was False, then flag2 would never be created in the function. That is why the error arises.

You can make flag1 and flag2 global inside the function as

```
flag1 = True
flag2 = True
def test(x):
    global flag1, flag2    

    if x % 2 ==0 :
         flag1 = True

    if x >=10:
         flag2 = True

    return flag1 and flag2

print(test(9))
```

Answer (score -3):

For Python2:

```
test = lambda x: 1 - x & 1 * x / 10
```